# PWM Modules vs Channels

Tags: microcontroller

I don't seem to understand, when a manufacturer states that their [microcontroller](http://www.ram-e-shop.com/ds/mcu/pic18f4431.pdf) has 2 PWM modules but 8 channels, does this mean I can drive only 2 motors but I have 8 pins (channels) to choose to output my PWM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular PIC has two "simple" CCP modules (that can be configured for basic PWM) and a single "power control" PWM module that can be configured to provide up to four, differential, PWM outputs, each with different duty cycles, offsets, dead times, etc, but all synchronised to the same timebase.

You could drive two simple DC motors with the CCP modules; their PWM signals would not be guaranteed to be synchronised (which probably isn't a problem) and the PWM resolution would be 10 bits.  Driving a complex motor with the CCP modules would be difficult if not impossible.

You could drive up to four simple DC motors with the power control PWM module; their PWM signals could (if you chose) be perfectly synchronised and the PWM resolution would be 14 bits.  Alternatively, you could drive a more complex motor (BDCM or stepper, perhaps) with the power control PWM module.

Comment: The data sheet says there are 6 motor control 14-bit PWM, why do you say 4?

Comment: There is one power control module with 3 channels (28-pin) or 4 channels (40/44-pin).  Each of the channels can be configured as differential and so can drive up to two output pins, giving 6 or 8 outputs respectively.